# grid items in the parent grid are not resizing horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web dev world. Currently I'm struggling on how to dynamically resize all items inside my grid `class = "card"` horizontally. Usually all my other project are having the same layout as this project and I don't know where did I screw up. Despite setting the min and max width, it doesn't seem to respect those values as it didn't resize the items correctly.Can you help me what is missing on my code? An explanation is much appreciated.

```css
/*
  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model.
*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
    2. Remove default margin
  */
* {
  margin: 0;
}

/*
    Typographic tweaks!
    3. Add accessible line-height
    4. Improve text rendering
  */
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/*
    5. Improve media defaults
  */
img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*
    6. Remove built-in form typography styles
  */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/*
    7. Avoid text overflows
  */
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

/*
    8. Create a root stacking context
  */
#root,
#__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}

:root {
  /* Primary Colors */
  --clr--gradient: hsl(6, 100%, 80%) to hsl(335, 100%, 65%);
  /* Neutral Colors */
  --clr--pale-blue: hsl(243, 100%, 93%);
  --clr--grayish-blue: hsl(229, 7%, 55%);
  --clr--dark-blue: hsl(228, 56%, 26%);
  --clr--very-dark-blue: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
}

:root {
  /* Font Family */
  --ff--primary: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  /* Font Size */
  --fs--regular: 14px;
  /* Font Weight */
  --fw--bold: 400;
  --fw--very-bold: 700;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

body {
  background: url("/images/bg-mobile.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: var(--clr--very-dark-blue);
  color: var(--clr--pale-blue);
  font-family: var(--ff--primary);
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.card__header, .card__info {
  background-color: var(--clr--dark-blue);
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
}
.card__header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
}
.card__header .logo img {
  width: 150px;
}
.card__header .flex-group {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.card__header .flex-group li {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: var(--clr--very-dark-blue);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css" class="css" />
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Fylo data storage component</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <style>
      .attribution {
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .attribution a {
        color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <main class="card">
        <section class="card__header">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
          </div>
          <ul class="flex-group">
            <li><img src="/images/icon-document.svg" alt="Document" /></li>
            <li><img src="/images/icon-folder.svg" alt="Folder" /></li>
            <li><img src="/images/icon-upload.svg" alt="Upload" /></li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="card__info">
          <p>You’ve used 815 GB of your storage</p>
          <input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="815" />
          <div>185 GB LEFT</div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
    <footer class="attribution">
      Challenge by
      <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
        >Frontend Mentor</a
      >. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your boxes inside `class = "card"` is resizing very well when adding more list items `<li>` in the list `<ul class="flex-group">`.

Please clarify, What boxes that do not resize dynamically?

Also, despite `max-width: 500px` property in `.card` rule, the boxes inside the grid will expand, if more list items are added, causing overflow. To prevent this overflow and maintain the layout, you can add `flex-wrap: wrap` property in `.card__header .flex-group` rule.

Btw, It is nice to use [BEM](https://getbem.com/) methodology despite you are new.

So, you say that when you resize the screen the `.card__header, .card__info` won't resize. I see that both are resized when more items are added to them.

---

#### Edit

The normal way a box is resized is when its content needs more space. This happens if the box has no fixed width.
To resize a box with respect to the size of the screen, you have two options:

- Use percentage values. `width: 70%` will resize a box to width = 0.7 × parent width, i.e. 70% of parent width. To make the box resize with respect to the screen, you need to make parents also have percentage values to their widths, till the direct children of the `body` element. Using this method with indirect deep-level elements to achieve this purpose may cause unintended results.
- The proper way to achieve the purpose, is to use `vw` values. `vw` stands for viewport width. `1vw` = 1% of the viewport width. This will resize your box with respect to `body` element, regardless of its deepness.

The other problem (to respect the max-width), you can add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.card__header .flex-group` as I mentioned above.

---

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Appreciated your response. I want that my class  `.card__header, .card__info` will respect the `max-width: 500px` of my parent class `card`. Using `min-width` is ok but when I use `max-width` it only stuck at 320px even though I resize the screen to its max width. Also if I shrink it down the page, content is cut off horizontally on the right.